# Is it advisable to use Serial.write in an ISR when loop() routinely uses Serial.read?

Tags: serial, i2c, interrupt, softwareserial, system-design

I do not know much electronics.

I have Nano v3 as I2C master, it reads 5-byte packets (of delimtted data) from PC's USB port, processes it and forwards it.

I now need to implement a way to signal PC if something went wrong down the line. I don't want to clutter I2C channel and its just a flag so I think interrupt is best for my purpose.

While writing the ISR function I am not sure if its advisable to write data using Serial, because loop might have read 2-3 bytes of the 5-byte message packet. And I don't know if it will overwrite data coming from PC or what...

**What will happen if I Serial.write(0x1) (suddenly, in an ISR function) while loop() was reading data from same Serial**?

I don't know how to test this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading and writing of serial data are separate functions. When you `.write()` you just append the data to the TX buffer. When you `.read()` you just take the next character from the RX buffer.

All actual sending and receiving, and filling/emptying of the buffers is done inside the ISRs for the UART module.

That said, you *really* shouldn't use `Serial` inside an ISR. This is because the sending and receiving is done by an ISR, and if you are in *your* ISR then the sending can never happen until you leave your ISR.  For the odd occasional byte it's not really a problem, but if the TX buffer fills up `Serial.write()` will block until the TX ISR has sent some data - which won't happen since your ISR is blocking the TX ISR.

So it's best to avoid any `Serial` operations inside an ISR. Instead you would normally set flags and values in an ISR then check for those flags in `loop()` to report anything.

Comment: Roger that. Yeah I am writing just 1 byte and then error handling will take over. I'll mark as answer soon, thanks.